# change journalCompressor to none - not default snappy

Tags: mongodb, compression, mongodb-3.4, wiredtiger

Quote from [ObjectRocket Support](http://objectrocket.com/)

> Hi, Fyodor! The `journalCompressor` setting is specifically related to
>   the journal files. Journals are typically not compressed because
>   compressing them causes additional latency when flushing the data from
>   the WiredTiger memory cache to the disk. This latency trickles down to
>   the write concern.
>   `journalCompressor none` is a default value in our configurations.

ObjectRocket seems to understand something about DBaaS

> [ObjectRocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ObjectRocket) is a cloud database (DBaaS) company based in Austin,
>   Texas, specializing in NoSQL datastores including MongoDB and
>   Redis. In 2013, they were acquired by Rackspace

What do you think about `journalCompressor` not snappy? Is this a valid config for DBaaS provider and best for most use cases?

```
storage:
   dbPath: "/data/mongodb"
   journal:
       enabled: true
   engine: "wiredTiger"
   wiredTiger:
       engineConfig:
           journalCompressor: none
           directoryForIndexes: "/indexes/mongodb/"
       collectionConfig:
           blockCompressor: snappy
       indexConfig:
           prefixCompression: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What do you think about `journalCompressor` not snappy? Is this a valid config for DBaaS provider and best for most use cases?

In general I would leave MongoDB settings at the default unless variations have proven to be beneficial for your common workloads (i.e. through actual testing and measurement). Snappy compression/decompression typically does not have much overhead and I/O is often more of a resource constraint than CPU. The default settings are intended to be "best for most use cases" and are more widely tested/used in MongoDB deployments and continuous integration tests.

The size limit on WiredTiger journal files is 100MB; when the journal file size limit is reached WiredTiger creates a new journal file and syncs the previous journal file to disk. With the default `journalCompressor` setting of `snappy` individual journal files can contain more data than with no compression. Without compression, more journal files will be created and there will be more journal I/O.

The right tradeoff for CPU vs I/O usage will vary based on your deployments and workloads. If your deployments have CPU to spare, you could also consider testing `zlib` compression (expecting better compression but more CPU usage).

If you are concerned about I/O contention between the journal and data files in your `dbPath` or want to do finer tuning given journal writes are sequential rather than random, another option would be to symlink the [journal directory](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/journaling/#journal-directory) to a separate mount point. This approach may affect your backup strategy (e.g. if you are relying on filesystem snapshots), however since you are already using the [`directoryForIndexes`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.directoryForIndexes) option I suspect you are already aware of this caveat.

For more configuration suggestions for production deployments, see the [Production Notes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-notes/) in the MongoDB manual.